Text inside a pygame_gui textbox disappears after changing it - pygame_gui library
I am using the pygame_gui library. I am trying to make a textbox that when pressed enter it will print the text inside the box to the console and reset it (so the textbox will be empty).
It does indeed resets the textbox but for some reason the textbox doesnt get any new input until I click somewhere in the background and click again on the textbox and only then it shows the text it gets.
The code:
import pygame_gui, pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((500,500))
manager.set_window_resolution((500,500))

text_box = pygame_gui.elements.UITextEntryLine(relative_rect=pygame.Rect(200,200,100,50), manager=manager, object_id='#text')

run=True
while run:
    UI_refresh = clock.tick(30)/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: run=False
        elif event.type==pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED and event.ui_object_id == '#text':
            print(text_box.text)
            text_box.set_text('') #here the text of the texbox is reset.

        manager.process_events(event)
    manager.update(UI_refresh)

    screen.fill('white')
    manager.draw_ui(screen)

    pygame.display.update()

I tried instead of reseting the textbox to set the text of it to some other value like 'A' (I changed the line text_box.set_text('') to text_box.set_text('A') ) but the textbox was still shown to be empty for some reason and I had the same problem.
Plus I should mention that when setting the text it does show the changes for a bit less than a second before it disappears until I click somewhere on the screen and again on the textbox to show the changes.

I have gone through the source and I found out that if we add the line text_box.redraw() right after the set_text it fixes the problem, so the updated code is:
import pygame_gui, pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((500,500))
manager.set_window_resolution((500,500))

text_box = pygame_gui.elements.UITextEntryLine(relative_rect=pygame.Rect(200,200,100,50), manager=manager, object_id='#text')

run=True
while run:
    UI_refresh = clock.tick(30)/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: run=False
        elif event.type==pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED and event.ui_object_id == '#text':
            print(text_box.text)
            text_box.set_text('') #here the text of the texbox is reset.
            text_box.redraw() #this line fixes the problem.

        manager.process_events(event)
    manager.update(UI_refresh)

    screen.fill('white')
    manager.draw_ui(screen)

    pygame.display.update()


A patch that I made for a bug that I stumbled upon a while back (when some of the text is selected by a cursor and a key is pressed t replace that selected text with a letter, then the whole text vanishes - it's only a visual bug, if a redraw is forced, like clicking off and clicking again the TextEntryLine, then the expected text is seen) which I think is caused by the same issue (the code that replaces the selection also uses set_text internally. I've checked that using this patch also fixes the issue - also it's applied to set_text itself (of DrawableShape and not TextEntryLine, because set_text in TextEntryLine only validates the text and then just calls DrawableShape.set_text, so other elements that are using this buggy function should also be fixed).
def patch1():
    from pygame_gui.core.drawable_shapes import DrawableShape

    old = DrawableShape.set_text

    def insert(self: DrawableShape, text: str):
        old(self, text)
        self.full_rebuild_on_size_change()

    DrawableShape.set_text = insert


patch1()
del patch1

